# Algorithm to always get oldest array index based on position of newest

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

This is almost an impossible question to ask, but any advice on the algorithm would be greatly appreciated (I will explain the best I can);

I have an array of size ~4000 bytes which contains data in byte format.

For this demonstration, I am going to simplify things a bit; say it's size 7 (to represent 'blocks' of data, not single values!);

```
 |  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |
```

I am adding a value at position 0, with the reset of the array being '0'

**key: N = newest, O = oldest, X = Filled**

```
 |  N  |    |    |    |    |    |    |
```

I now need to add another value. this will be entered at the next available position.

```
 |  O  |  N  |    |    |    |    |    |
```

So now position [0] is now the 'oldest' part of the array, and position [1] is the newest.

**This has been (currently) worked out by looking all the way right, seeing no values, and then starting from position [0] until it sees a value.**

Let's add another:

```
 |  O  |  X  |  N  |    |    |    |    |
```

Note, the oldest value hasn't changed position, as it is still the oldest part of the array.

I am now going to 'clear' the oldest part of the array (in this example it is currently pos [0]). this makes 'O' move over to the next position.

```
 |    |  O  |  N  |    |    |    |    |
```

Lets add another value. Since it will go to the first 'empty' space, it will go to position [0]; this means the first position is now at position [0].

```
 |  N  |  O  |  X  |    |    |    |    |
```

I'm going to clear another one now; so again, by **looking from the right of the newest value**, I see a value is at position 1. So i'm going to clear it.

```
 |    |    |  O/N  |    |    |    |    |
```

this means position [2] is now both the newest and oldest value available.

Adding another makes;

```
 |  N  |    |  O  |    |    |    |    |
```

Adding another;

```
 |  X  |  N  |  O  |    |    |    |    |
```

and adding another;

```
 |  X  |  X  |  O  |  N  |    |    |    |
```

I am looking to delete the oldest value now. So by looking right from position of the 'newest' variable, I see pos[0] has a value, so that must be it.  **UH-OH** that's not the oldest value!

---

As you can (hopefully) tell, I am unable to get the oldest ticket by looking to the right for my next value - this problem only occurs every so often, and has been hard to find a solution.

I only know the index of the **most recent value** added, and this is very hard to find a solution. (lots of scribbliing and diagrams have been attempted, lots of scrumpled up paper).

So if anyone had any ideas as to how I could ALWAYS find the oldest value's index, I would be greatly appreciative! (I also know this is quite a complex question, so if anyone wants/needs clarification, I'll be happy to edit/explain further!)  I have tagged c#, but realistically I only need a BASIC algorithm for any progress to be honest!!!

====================================================================================

**EDIT**

Answers have suggested to allocate to the right of the 'newest' position;
like:

```
 |    |    |  O  |  N  |     |     |    | 
 |    |    |  O  |  X  |  N  |     |    | 
 |    |    |  O  |  X  |  X  |  N  |    | 
 |    |    |  O  |  X  |  X  |  X  |  N |
 |  N |    |  O  |  X  |  X  |  X  |  X |  
 |  X |  N |  O  |  X  |  X  |  X  |  X |
```

Which I think COULD work, but anyone know if this would fail (say, I removed a value at a certain time/etc?)

Comment: Can you change the allocation policy by always adding data in the next block after the most recent insert (wrapping around if necessary)?

Comment: you mean like the **edit** i made a minute ago? I think it could work, but I just need a min or two to see if it would work 100% of the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are forced to use an array; if not then you should consider switching to an adequate data structure such as a **[Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx)**.

If you are indeed forced to use an array, and can only keep a pointer to the latest block, then i would recommend always adding new blocks the to the right of the latest block, with a index wrapping back to zero at array size.

This lets you determine what the oldest block is by looking to the blocks right of the latest block, until you find a non empty block: this is your oldest block. Null it to remove it from the array and carry on :)

Let's illustrate:

```
 | N |   |   |   |   |   |   |   // newBlockIndex at 0, adding, newBlockIndex becomes 1
 | X | N |   |   |   |   |   |   // newBlockIndex at 1, adding, newBlockIndex becomes 2
 | X | X | N |   |   |   |   |   // newBlockIndex at 2, adding, newBlockIndex becomes 3
 |   | X | N |   |   |   |   |   // newBlockIndex at 3, removing, no item before index 0, we delete it
 |   | X | X | N |   |   |   |   // newBlockIndex at 3, adding, newBlockIndex becomes 4
...
```

**EDIT TO ADD**
Regarding your edit, I think the mechanism is quite robust. Even if you were to remove an item (any item, even the latest one) by error, the next operation can succeed because latest and newest are defined in regards to their position to the current index. Newest item is the first on the left of the index, oldest the first on the right.

Even if you don't check for your array size and fill it completely (which I don't recommend, though), the algorithm will overwrite the oldest item with the newest: it may not be good but it is coherent with the notion of a queue. Of course if the array fills up you can always decide to allocate a new one larger and copy the current one to the larger array

Comment: @Sammy, you are right to guess it has to be an array. Would I be right in thinking that you're saying to always allocate, rather than to a free 'space', is to allocate instead to the next available position of the right of the newest index?

Comment: I think you mean "you determine what the oldest block is by looking to the blocks **left** of the latest block" don't you?

Comment: @terribleProgrammer That's exactly it, since as you remarked you cannot try and fill the start of the array without additional information (ie reimplementing a linked list)

Comment: @Chris In fact you can find the oldest block by looking into both direction: either right until you find a non empty space, or left until you find the last non empty block (that is not the latest block if array is filled)

Comment: @samy: I just realised that on rereading. I'd misunderstood how it worked but you are moving right over the empty space til you get to the first non empty rather than going left over the full blocks til you find an empty one and then going back one. The going back one probably makes your way better.

Comment: @samy, i've added a short edit to my question - is that what you mean? Would there be a time where this would 'break'?

Comment: Answered: It really depends what you mean by break. You can make a mistake and manually erase an item you didn't mean to, but the behavior will keep working. See my additional edit

Comment: I've just read it; and agree it's pretty robust. :) I would be completely filling the thing, though, and if no values were removed, i would be happy enough for them to be overwritten. So thank you for your help, it wasn't the way i was thinking of, but am very glad to get a different view on this. I've been screwing my head all day! I'm actually using this as part of a NETMF borad project, so have used the complete **internalFlashStorage** of ~3500B, with the rest going to other 'bits and bobs'.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a queue data structure.

Queues can be conveniently implemented with a circular buffer where you have a head index and a tail index.

Head and Tail are both initially set to zero.

Add a new element by writing it to where Tail points, then increment Tail. Wrap as needed if incrementing makes it go off the end of the array.

Delete an old element by incrementing Head. Again, wrap as needed if incrementing makes it go off the end of the array.

Head always points at the oldest element. 
Tail always points to the right of the newest element.

Comment: It has to be an array @500 - Internal Server Error as it's for a NETMF. board with limited memory (i.e, I only have enough memory to allocate for a single index - (yes- it's that tight on internal storage!) :(

Answer (score -1):

Use a `System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>`, where `T` is a byte block.

```
Queue<byte[]> queue = new Queue<byte[]>();
byte[] block;

queue.Enqueue(new byte[] { 10, 11, 12, 13 });
queue.Enqueue(new byte[] { 20, 21, 22, 23 });
queue.Enqueue(new byte[] { 30, 31, 32, 33 });
block = queue.Dequeue();
queue.Enqueue(new byte[] { 40, 41, 42, 43 });
block = queue.Dequeue();
block = queue.Dequeue();
queue.Enqueue(new byte[] { 50, 51, 52, 53 });
queue.Enqueue(new byte[] { 60, 61, 62, 63 });
queue.Enqueue(new byte[] { 70, 71, 72, 73 });
block = queue.Dequeue();
// ...
```

`Dequeue` always removes the oldest element!

---

Since you have clarified in comments that it must be an array, here is a solution that encapsulates an array-queue in a class. It treats consecutive elements as data block of a defined size. It also allows you to access array elements by index and the array itself. This not typical for queues, but since you need the array...

```
public class ArrayBlocksQueue<T>
{
    private T[] _array;
    private int _in, _out, _count, _length, _blockSize;

    public ArrayBlocksQueue(int maxBlocks, int blockSize)
    {
        _length = maxBlocks * blockSize;
        _blockSize = blockSize;
        _array = new T[_length];
    }

    public void Enqueue(params T[] block)
    {
        if (block == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        if (block.Length != _blockSize) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Data does not have required block size.");
        }
        if (_count + _blockSize > _length) {
            throw new ApplicationException("Queue is full");
        }
        block.CopyTo(_array, _in);
        _in = (_in + _blockSize) % _length;
        _count += _blockSize;
    }

    public T[] Dequeue()
    {
        if (_count == 0) {
            throw new ApplicationException("Queue is empty");
        }
        T[] temp = new T[_blockSize];
        System.Array.Copy(_array, _out, temp, 0, _blockSize);
        _out = (_out + _blockSize) % _length;
        _count -= _blockSize;
        return temp;
    }

    public int Count { get { return _count; } }

    public int BlockCount { get { return _count / _blockSize; } }

    public T[] Array { get { return _array; } }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!IsIndexValid(index)) {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }
            return _array[index];
        }
        set
        {
            if (!IsIndexValid(index)) {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }
            _array[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public bool IsIndexValid(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= _length) {
            return false;
        }
        if (_count == _length) {
            return true;
        }
        return _out > _in
            ? index < _in || index >= _out
            : index >= _out && index < _in;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP has clarified in comments to other answers that it must be an array. (not the downvoter since i assume you just hadn't seen this).

Comment: upvoted to negate the downvote, as your answer is still (technically)correct

Comment: I exchanged my initial `ArrayQueue<T>` by an implementation working with blocks within the array.